# what is unix/linux internals?

Tags: linux, unix, internals

When somebody asks me about how strong you are in **unix/linux internals** ? What do they really mean ?

Though i have some idea, i would like to hear from some experts that, what is really meant by unix/linux internals.

My ideas are, i have to be strong in,

- linux boot process
- user creation
- how does a command executes
- filesystem related details
- process details

I would like to know, whether this is sufficient or something else there ?

Update: I edited this question to add more details, if possible reopen the questions for answers?!

Comment: Yep !!! Closed... I am also in the same confusion that what do my boss says by become expert in unix/linux internals. And now found that, it is not only me, and many others have this confusion !!!!

Comment: Maybe try asking in programmers.stackexchange.com . This is not really question which belongs in stackoverflow. Or maybe better ask your boss what he means by that, he might have a different opinion (especially if he's not technical).

Answer (score 2):

The internal design of the components of the Linux operating system (i.e. the kernel).

Comment: does this is the only thing they mean ? or some thing else has to be added. Note: i updated the question accordingly.